# arquivos batch - encontrar diretorio do arquivo atual

Tags: cmd, batch

Eu tenho um arquivo batch que faz o cmd apontar para outro diretório.
Mas em um certo momento, preciso que ele volte para o diretório do próprio arquivo batch. É possível  fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro uso do **cd /d %~dp0:** 
**cd /d** altera o **drive atual** + o **diretório atual** para o **drive** e o **diretório** onde o **batch** foi **inicialmente executado**:

```bat
:: você pode criar uma variável:
set "_cd_batch_path=cd /d "%~dp0" "

:: ou simplesmente usar o command:

cd /d "%~dp0"
```

sempre que for necessário voltar use a variavel **`%_cd_batch_path%`** ou simplesmente **`"cd /d %~dp0"`**:

```bat
%_cd_batch_path%

:: ou :: 

!_cd_batch_path!

:: ou ainda ::

cd /d "%~dp0"
```

Comment: Olá caro kapptuz, entendi o que disse sobre o >null e >nul, quando notar erros de digitação assim vocÊ pode comentar diretamente na resposta, somos uma comunidade, toda critica e revisão de texto e código é aceita. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

No início do código pode salvar o diretório que o arquivo batch está com o comando:

```
set backDir=%cd%
```

E depois voltar para ele com o comando:

```
cd %backDir%
```